# Add VB.NET to Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In the past I have only used Visual Studio 2010 Professional for C#, but now I need to work on a little bit of Visual Basic. When I go to create a project it only shows C# project templates. I am assuming when I installed Visual Studio 2010, I only installed C#.

How do I now install VB.NET support?

I tried following a MS tutorial: I went to Control Panel and selected Change/Uninstall on Visual Studio, but then it asked me to insert a CD, of which I have none since it was donwloaded.

Comment: Do you still have the downloaded file? Ultimately you will have to us the VS installer to achieve what your trying to do.

Comment: This is not possible, you can't only install one language.  Open the "Other Languages" node.

Comment: Do you have by any chance the c# express version of Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out. (win7) Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Uninstall/Change on Visual Studio -> then when you hit the Add/Remove features and you get the popup asking about the cd (which is where I assumed i was stuck before) if you hit Download it takes you to the dialog where you choose additional languages to install and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for my earlier flippant comment, and offer you
http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2010-Professional/3000-2212_4-10618634.html

Comment: i guess i need to clarify. i dont want to reinstall the whole application and as for your "flippant comment" it is the 60 day trial lol

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but i did the simplest solution ,since i had my .iso(visual studio express) file i had downloaded  I used my winrar to extract files ,went to VBExpress ,open the folder and click on the setup and it all worked out  successfully...